# Глупые вопросы по шифрованию

Tags: шифрование

Помогите пожалуйста с о последовательностью действий. Я знаю есть симметричное шифрование вроде  AES и ассиметричное вроде RSA. И так же есть алгоритм Диффи-Хеллмана, с помощи которого выявляется общий секретный ключ. Так вот 1) Как Диффи-Хеллман относится к шифрофанию? Это отдельный вид или подпункт двух других шифрований? Можете пожалуйста объяснить последовательность , что за чем идет. Что-то вроде получатель и отправитель соединяются находят общий секретный ключ, а потом уже происходит ассим. и симм. шифрование?? Очень интересна последовательность все этого.

Comment: Алгоритм Диффи Хэлмона - это частный случай асинхронного шифрования

Comment: @Александр А как еще находят общий секретный ключ в ассиметричном шифровании? И как его находят в симметричном шифровании? В двух словах если можешь.